# What kind of capacitors are these small, cube-shaped surface-mount components?

Tags: pcb, identification, surface-mount

Complete newbie question...

I'm troubleshooting a PCB that includes 4x very small cube-shaped components, labeled `C2`, `C3`, `C5`, and `C6` so I presume they're capacitors.  They're soldered in parallel and there's no visible markings on them, but appear to be ceramic and are approximately 1mm on all dimensions.

[image: mystery capacitors]

Comment: MLCC. Multi Layered Ceramic Capacitor.

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of solder.

Comment: @Dampmaskin yeah, it stuck out as the only visual issue and was pretty baffling to my newbie eyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As winny said, they're multi-layer ceramic capacitors. They're almost never marked, so the only way to figure out what they are is to measure them with an LCR meter. You'll have to take them out of the circuit to get an accurate reading unfortunately.

For debugging, a quick check you may want to perform is to see if there's a short across these caps. Of course that could mean a short anywhere in the power net, but MLCC's like this often fail shorted. This is especially common when they're subject to mechanical or thermal stress. The soldering job makes that seem like a likely possibility.

Comment: Thanks!  I presume they're non-polarized since they're unmarked?

Comment: @STW That is correct.

Comment: Yes, the over-soldering makes them less resistant to stress.